# Concat result from Cursor into a single listview element

Tags: android, listview, concatenation

I have a android listview and it has a two_line_list_item layout.... text1 and text2

I have a SQL query which returns me my Cursor.... in the below example I have set NameA from the SQL to text1 and NameB to text2

```
        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{"NameA", "NameB"};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter matches = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, MatchesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(matches);
```

How could I go about concatenating the two names (without changing my SQL query) so text1 will be "NameA v NameB"...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In your Query do

```
NameA || "v" || NameB AS NameAB
```

Then remove the second textView (android.R.text2)

In your return projections put "NameAB" leave out the other columns (keep KEY_ID) as you will no longer be needing them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to write custom Adapter which extends BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way would be using 3 views in your xml:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" vs "
        android:textSize="30dp" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
```

wrapping everything in a horizontal LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int listItemLayout;
    private String[] nameAs;
    private String[] nameBs;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int listItemLayout, String[] nameAs, String[] nameBs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listItemLayout = listItemLayout;
        this.nameAs = nameAs;
        this.nameBs = nameBs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null)
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(listItemLayout, null);

            TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView1.setText(nameAs[position] + " v " + nameBs[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Now all you need to do is to modify a bit of your database access function to return you the two arrays of names, and pass them to the constructor of `CustomAdapter`

Eventually, call:

```
CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, nameAs, nameBs);
setListAdapter(myAdapter);
```

As a note, please also try to follow the [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) suggested in the link.